# Enable Focusable of edit textbox depend on checkbox is not working after disable the edit textbox in android

Tags: android

I have tried to disable and enable the focusing of edittext box  depend on checkbox. While checkbox is checked, the textbox is focusable and if it is not checked, the textbox should be non-focusable. When i tried to enable focusing the text box after disable the textbox using the checkbox, it is not working. Here is my code.

```
 check_box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked){
                    txt_time.setFocusable(true);
                } else {
                    txt_time.setFocusable(false);
                }

            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

enable:

```
txt_time.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
txt_time.setFocusable(true);
```

disable:

```
txt_time.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
txt_time.setFocusable(false);
```

instead of

enable:

```
txt_time.setFocusable(true);
```

disable:

```
txt_time.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
txt_time.setFocusable(true);
```

try

```
txt_time.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: When i use your answer i got an undefined error message. So i use        txt_time.setEnabled(true);    my code is working well..

Comment: can you use in xml code, android:editable="false" or you can use inputType because "editable" is deprecated..